# Subject-auxiliary inversion in affirmative answers?

Tags: grammar, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I came across a sentence as follows.

> Most teachers attest to the superior intelligence Ralph has
> displayed. Because of this, one of the teachers wants to register him
> in a local quiz show. When he is asked about it, Ralph exclaims, “**Boy,
> would I!**” Everyone is excited about the big quiz show.

Ralph is not making a question, nor is he making a negative statement or anything that would justify inverting the word order as far as I know.

I would like to know why the person responded using subject-auxiliary inversion?

Comment: It's a [rhetorical question](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zmfc7ty/articles/z7dyvk7). Presumably Ralph was asked "Would you like to take part in the quiz show?" He means "Of course I would!"

Comment: @KateBunting I don't think it's even a question. It's a statement that happens to have subject-auxiliary inversion, as questions also do

Comment: No, Kate is correct.  It's definitely a rhetorical question.  Some grammarians suggest *all* rhetorical questions should drop the question mark. Regardless of lack of a question mark, it is a question.